# Смена сцен в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    public Stage  primaryStage = new Stage();
    ImageView iv1;
    public void start(  Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root= new AnchorPane();
         Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,600,400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("SocOpros");
        Image img = new Image("bgg.png");
        iv1 = new ImageView();
        iv1.setImage(img);

        iv1.setVisible(true);


        Button btn = new Button("TEST");//создание кнопки           


        btn.setVisible(true);
        btn.setLayoutX(20);
       btn.setLayoutY(40);
       root.getChildren().addAll(iv1,btn);
        btn.setOnAction(new RotateImg());//установка действия на кнопку


        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public class RotateImg implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            AnchorPane root2= new AnchorPane();
             Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2,600,400);
             stage.setScene(scene2);
               stage.show();

        }
    }

}
```

При нажатии на кнопку появляется новое окно как и необходимо. Но также необходимо закрыть предыдущее окно, но я не знаю каким образом сделать primary stage глобальным объектом, чтобы с ним можно было работать и в методе RotateImg.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1:
Изменить слушатель так чтобы он при открытии окна закрывал предыдущее:

```
btn.setOnAction(lsn -> {
    new RotateImg();
    primaryStage.close();
});
```

Вариант 2:
Вы пишете "чтобы с ним можно было работать и в методе RotateImg", но у вас там не метод а внутренний класс, если заменить его на метод, тогда можно будет ему передать Stage и закрывать, или делать с ней что угодно в этом методе:

```
public class JavaFXApplication23 extends Application {

    public Stage  primaryStage = new Stage();
    ImageView iv1;
    public void start(  Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root= new AnchorPane();
         Scene scene1 = new Scene(root,600,400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("SocOpros");
        Image img = new Image("bgg.png");
        iv1 = new ImageView();
        iv1.setImage(img);

        iv1.setVisible(true);


        Button btn = new Button("TEST");//создание кнопки           


        btn.setVisible(true);
        btn.setLayoutX(20);
       btn.setLayoutY(40);
       root.getChildren().addAll(iv1,btn);
        btn.setOnAction(rotat ->{//кнопка теперь исполняет метод при нажатии
            rotateImg(primaryStage);//методу передается сцена в качестве аргумента
        });


        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    public void rotateImg(Stage stg){
        stg.close();//закрываем предыдущую сцену.
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            AnchorPane root2= new AnchorPane();
             Scene scene2 = new Scene(root2,600,400);
             stage.setScene(scene2);
               stage.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но при первом способе окно закрывается первым а второе не открывается. Второй способ полностью рабочий.